# User comma in wmic password

Tags: cmd, wmic

in wmic in cmd i want to enter user and password but my passowrd includes comma and cmd cant read it
here is error i get

> ,-ALias not found
>   and here is my commmand

```
wmic /user:testusername /password:qwer,ty
```

in passwords without comma works find

Comment: Try quotation (`wmic /user:testusername /password:"qwer,ty"`) or escaping (`wmic /user:testusername /password:qwer^,ty`)...

Comment: i tried both solutions but still get same error

Comment: Damn! Seems `wmic` handles the `,` in a particular way; my suggestions would have helped only to overcome potential loss caused by the parser `cmd.exe`, but I should have realised that the error message you posted still contains the `,`, so it is received by `wmic`. Sorry, but I have not got any further ideas to solve that, I just found out that even `\,` fails...